# r gets all possible multiple optimal solutions

Tags: r, optimization

Let $X \sim N(0,1)$, with pdf $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$. Consider a Cauchy variable $Y \sim q$, with pdf $q(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\left(1+x^2\right)}$. We can manually get that $\frac{f_X(x)}{q_Y(x)} \leq M$ for $M=\sqrt{2 \pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$  when $x=\pm 1$.

In R, I have tried

```r
f <- function(x) dnorm(x) / dcauchy(x)
curve(f, -4, 4, n = 200, col = 4); grid()
out = optimize(f, interval = c(-4, 4), maximum = TRUE)
out
$maximum #x=-1
[1] -0.9999994

$objective #M=sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-1/2)
[1] 1.520347
points(out$maximum, out$objective, pch = 20, col = "red", cex = 1.5)
```

while the output only shows `x=-1` (missing `x=1`)!

Surely, we can shrink the interval `c(-4, 4)` to `c(0, 4)` to get `x=1`, while how we can  get both $x=\pm 1$ still using  `c(-4, 4)`. Any other optimal functions  or packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I guess what you are after is "***local maximums***" within a given range, instead of "***global maximum***".

---

You can try `findpeaks` from `pracma` library, instead of `optim`, e.g.,

```
library(pracma)
fpk <- function(f, lb, ub) {
    x <- seq(lb, ub, by = 1e-5)
    pks <- findpeaks(f(x))
    list(maximum = pks[, 1], objective = x[pks[, 2]])
}
```

or a custom function with base R

```
fpk <- function(f, lb, ub) {
    x <- seq(lb, ub, by = 1e-5)
    y <- f(x)
    d <- embed(diff(y), 2)
    objective <- x[which(d[, 2] >= 0 & d[, 1] <= 0) + 1]
    maximum <- f(objective)
    list(maximum = maximum, objective = objective)
}
```

and you will see

```
> fpk(f, -4, 4)
$maximum
[1] 1.520347 1.520347

$objective
[1] -1  1


> fpk(f, -4, 0)
$maximum
[1] 1.520347

$objective
[1] -1


> fpk(f, 0, 4)
$maximum
[1] 1.520347

$objective
[1] 1
```

Comment: Great of `findpeaks`! Exactly what I want, tks! @ThomasIsCoding